# compare table row if a cell is empty then I have no result with table.select although the conditions are met

Tags: vb.net

if e.g. Sector_Pr_1 is empty or Sector_Pr_2 is empty or and Sector_Pr_3 is empty then I get no result with table.select if the conditions are correct
If I then enter a 0 in the empty column, I get the correct result
MyAr(x,0) contains the number of occurrences of a number
MyAr(x,1) are numbers from 1 to 4
all sector columns are integer

```vb
For i = 0 To 3
    Dim LeastCommon As Integer = MyAr(i, 0)

    For t = i + 1 To 3
        Dim MostCommon As Integer = MyAr(t, 0)

        If MostCommon - LeastCommon > 1 Then
            Dim NumPlus As Integer = MyAr(t, 1)' number to be replaced by NumMin if not present in "Sector_Pr_1"  and not in " Sector_Pr_2" and not in "Sector_Pr_3"
            Dim NumMin As Integer = MyAr(i, 1)
                    
         dr = DT.Select("Sector_Pr_4=" & NumPlus & " and Sector_Pr_1 <>" & NumMin & " and Sector_Pr_2 <>" & NumMin & " and Sector_Pr_3 <>" & NumMin)

            If dr.Count > 0 Then
                dr(0)("Sector_Pr_4") = NumMin
            End If
         End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have cleaned up the formatting of your code., Given that VS will format your code automatically, there's no excuse to be posting messy code that is harder for us to read. It's your responsibility to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Making your post as clear and readable is possible is part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to account for `NULL` in your filter. `NULL` is no value so it needs to be treated separately to values. You're basically looking for records where a particular field is `NULL` or it has a value that is not equal to something else. That's two criteria so that's how you have to write your logic. This would be for one column:

```vb
dr = DT.Select($"Sector_Pr_4 = {NumPlus} AND (Sector_Pr_1 IS NULL OR Sector_Pr_1 <> {NumMin})")
```

You then do the same thing for the other two columns.

Note that I have used string interpolation instead of all that concatenation to make the code more readable and thus less error-prone.

Comment: thanks jmcilhinney, does exactly what i needed
and sorry for the messy code she copied directly from the class